# The wavelength of photons emitted

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, wavelength, photon-emission

If for example an electron in a hydrogen atom moved from $n=2$ to $n=1$, how can you find the wavelength of the emitted photon? I know that the energy involved is $$E = -13.6\ {\rm eV} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{n_1^2} - \frac{1}{n_2^2}\right),$$  but I'm not sure how to find the wavelength from that.

Comment: Do you know how frequency relates to energy?

Comment: @DanielSank Oh it is E = hc/lambda , I see now. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equation $E=hc/\lambda$. In case you don't know, $h$ is Planck's constant and $\lambda$ is the wavelength in nanometers. Convert electron volts to joules ($E$) using $1\ {\rm eV} =
1.60217662 \times 10^{-19}\ \rm J$. Planck's constant is $6.62607004 \times 10^{-34}\ {\rm m^2\ kg\, /\, s}$.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a mechanism that would allow an orbital transition to generate the electromagnetic wave packet associated with a photon. In the Bohr model one might imagine the electron spiraling down from a larger orbit to a smaller one, but that would produce a photon with a variable wavelength, and does not work well with resonant standing wave orbitals.